# differentiation with multiple variables

Tags: calculus

I have an equation
$$e=ab+c$$

If I differentiate w.r.t $c$ then should I get the answer of $1$?

Comment: It is true that $\frac{\partial}{\partial c}(ab+c)=1$.

Comment: So you want do differentiate $e(c)=ab+c$? In this case it is true that $\frac{de}{dc}=1$.

Comment: How are $a,b,e$ related to $c$?

Comment: It's true that $de/dc = a(db/dc) + b(da/dc) + 1.$ If $a$ and $b$ are constants (not varying when $c$ varies) then $db/dc = da/dc = 0$. Then, depending on what the question is, the answer could be $1.$